# WordPress automatic login after reset password

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a custom WordPress login module and I faced some problem.
If a user finishes his survey on the site he will be registered with his email address and then password reset link will be sent to the user's email box.
If he click the link he will be redirected to reset password panel.
Once he set password he is redirected to login panel, but I want to make him automatically logged in and redirected to a specific page.
So the idea is to remove unnecessary login step.
Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally managed it by myself with below code. Hope this code helps the others!

```
add_action( 'validate_password_reset', 'rsm_redirect_after_rest', 10, 2 );
function rsm_redirect_after_rest($errors, $user) {
    if ( ( ! $errors->get_error_code() ) && isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {
        reset_password( $user, $_POST['pass1'] );

        list( $rp_path ) = explode( '?', wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
        $rp_cookie = 'wp-resetpass-' . COOKIEHASH;
        setcookie( $rp_cookie, ' ', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, $rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true );

        wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
        do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login, $user );//`[Codex Ref.][1]
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Congrats on coming up with an answer yourself, and thanks for posting it for benefit of others.

Comment: What are `$rp_cookie` and `$rp_path` variables?

Comment: Hi @dboris, I updated my answer with the $rp_path and $rp_cookie.

Comment: wp_set_auth_cookie() will set the cookie for you, it's not required to manually setcookie.

Comment: Also, use wp_set_password() instead of reset_password() if you don't want admins to receive emails about password changes.

Comment: 'wp_login' action needs a second parameter as WP_User object:
`do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login, $user );`

Comment: @OmarTanti You are right. I updated my answer. Thanks